# bootstrap table-responsive not working on firefox mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I add table-responsive class to wrapper div of table and it work fine in all browsers except Firefox for mobile(android at least) and scroller not shown any idea?

p.s. I visit other questions in site but my table is normal table without fieldset or other thing that mentioned in other questions.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>foo</th>
                <th>foo</th>
                <th>foo</th>
                <th>foo</th>
                <th>foo</th>
                <th>foo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>foo</span>
                    till
                    <br>
                    <span>foo</span>
                </td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>
                    <a
                      style="min-width: 78px; display: inline-block;"
                      href="#"
                      class="addticket-modalrun btn btn-success btn-xs"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-price="100"
                      data-stock="100"
                      data-priceformat="100"
                      data-ticketid="11"
                      data-target="#addToCartModal">
                      foo
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mohsenkw can you please jsfiddle your code and send the link here ?
I will possibly fix it.

Thanks :)